# Models CTA and SRE in Biomod2

Tags: biomod2

I am looking forward to understanding the ensembling process of Biomod2.
In the Biomod2 description, the models CTA and SRE predict the species suitability as binary class ie 0 or 1
Whereas other models can predict the probability (i.e. value between 0 and 1).
If such is the case how can we ensemble models with probability output and binary output? If I don’t want to convert my models to binary

Can you help me with some explanation for this issue?

Looking forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 0):

Ensemble modeling in biomod is effectively just averaging all models in the ensemble (although weights can be given among other parameters). In this case, if you were to be making an ensemble of 2 models, the output would have three values, high, (high + low) / 2, low. Note that biomod models do not automataically rescale to be from 0-1000, so the high value could be between 600-1000 in my experience.

Also, CTA does not exclusively give binary outputs (although SRE does).